# Use transaction in Model.findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongoose, transactions

How can I use Model.findOneAndUpdate() in mongoose with a transaction?

I have a session object and I would like to commit the the findOneAndUpdate op as part of a transaction but don't know how to pass my session object.

```
const session = params?.mongoose?.session;

const doc = await this.Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { sequence: sequence },
  {
    $setOnInsert: { sequenceLength: sequenceLength },
    $inc: { value: 1 }
  },
  { upsert: true, new: true }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is a TypeScritp issue. The type definitions are incomplete and the `QueryFindOneAndUpdateOptions` interface should include `session?: ClientSession;`

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8396

Basically you would have to simply pass the session as an argument, but currently this throws a ts error.

```
const session = params?.mongoose?.session;

const doc = await this.Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  { sequence: sequence },
  {
    $setOnInsert: { sequenceLength: sequenceLength },
    $inc: { value: 1 }
  },
  { upsert: true, new: true, session: session }
);
```